# How to add parameters/switches to Eclipse/Maven Run Configuration

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I have Eclipse (Galileo) with m2eclipse, GWT Eclispe plugin and the GWT Maven plugin from codehaus installed.

I created a new "Maven Build" run configuration in Eclipse and have set the goal to `gwt:debug`.  When I run the configuration I get this error in my console:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.2:debug (default-cli) on project GWTExample: Command [[
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\java -Xmx512m -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE     -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=y -classpath 
...
<snip>
...
com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode -war "C:\Devel\EclipseProjects\GWTExample\war" -gen 
"C:\Devel\EclipseProjects\GWTExample\target\.generated" -logLevel INFO -port 8888
-startupUrl "my.test.Application/Application.html" my.test.Application
]] failed with status 1
-> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How do I add the -e or -X switch to a "Maven Build" configuration?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Click on the Project

Run As -> Maven build...

Goal -> gwt:debug -e -X

Run

Comment: Seems the opposite of obvious..."-X" is NOT a goal, it's an argument to the mvn command.

Comment: In recent versions of Eclipse, you can simply check the "Debug Output" checkbox on the debug/run configurations dialog box, which adds -X -e to your run.

Comment: This worked correctly also for the "-rf :<project_name>" option. Thank you.